# Needing a 5.1 studio in London

Tags: 5.1, studios, london

Hi all,

I am working on a film in South Africa but the producer is in London and wishes to have the sound mix sent to him for viewing. The producer has asked the studio here if we can find him a 5.1 studio in London to view the mix in it's various stages and then send it back with notes.

The budget is not great and the producer is not looking for a "high end" facility but he wants one that is certified for 5.1.

Can anyone recommend a studio in London that is not too expensive?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try art4noise.com, not sure on their prices but an awesome bunch of guys who really love what they do work there.